# How to convert array to specific array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is my array:

```
  Array(
[Priority] => 194.49
[Xpresspost] => 147.49
[Expedited] => 48.57
[Regular] => 48.57
```

)

I want to show my array like this:

```
'Priority'=> '194.49','Xpresspost'=>'40','Expedited'=> '48.57','Regular'=>'48.57'
```

Comment: use var_dump post your array

Comment: How are you getting your input Array(
[Priority] => 194.49
[Xpresspost] => 147.49
[Expedited] => 48.57
[Regular] => 48.57

Answer (score 2):

If you want your array to be printed in a single line like that you could use:

```
$array = array(
    'Priority' => 194.49,
    'Xpresspost' => 147.49,
    'Expedited' => 48.57,
    'Regular' => 48.57
);

$output = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $output[] = " '$key' => '$value'";
}
echo implode(',', $output);
```

Comment: Hi, @Hicaro it works like charm. Now i want to assign my array to some variable like this :
$neil = array('Priority'=> '194.49','Xpresspost'=>'40','Expedited'=> '48.57','Regular'=>'48.57'); How can i do that ?

Comment: Hey @NeilDhakal, the question is, were you trying to convert your array to a string or you wanted to convert the float numbers to string type and still have an array?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to return array like this from controller in codeigniter : return array('Priority' => '194.49', 'Xpresspost' => '147.49', 'Expedited' => '48.57', 'Regular' => '48.57');

Comment: I am still confused with what you want to do now. Do you want to make the string as a first element of a new array or convert it back to be an array?

Comment: You could do `foreach($array as $key => $value) {$array[$key] = "'$value'";}` then return the array itself as `return $array`.